# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a problem:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
float reload_distance = 15;
if(y > h + reload_distance)
{
    if(newNumberOfItemsToDisplay <= [self.arrPodsCanal count])
    {

        for (i=numberOfItemsToDisplay; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay; i++)
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        numberOfItemsToDisplay = newNumberOfItemsToDisplay;

        [self.myTable beginUpdates];

        [self.myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
        if (numberOfItemsToDisplay == totalNumberOfItems)
                [self.myTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.myTable endUpdates];
    }
}
}
```

In the last block to update the UITableView I get this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'

The problem is when newNumberOfItemsToDisplay == [self.arrPodsCanal count]

Comment: You are trying to delete section 1 which doesn't exist. Only section 0 exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that:

```
[self.myTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

To:

```
[self.myTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: with "0" I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (50) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (5 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: So now you have to return proper value from numberOfRowsInSection and return 0. It looks like some of rows are also inserted

Comment: my numberOfRowsInSection:
{
    if (section == 0)
        return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
    else
        return 1;
}

Comment: so probably numberOfItemsToDisplay is wrong value for that case - you should update it when you insert / delete rows.